# javafx - Graphics Device initialization failed for : es2, sw M1 MacOS

Tags: java, javafx

So, when I try to run my JavaFX Code sample on my M1 MBA I get this long error.
https://pastebin.com/3EBekwVF

I am using macOS aarch64 javafx sdk from
https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

I added the SDK to the Java Build Path via right clicking on the project -> selecting Java Build Path -> switching to Library tab -> add all .jars and src.zip with "Add External Jars"
Then I went into my run configurations and added this line to my vm arguments

```
--module-path /Users/lockna/eclipse-workspace/javafx-sdk-18/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I tried some fixes I found on reddit or other stack overflow posts, but they didn't work for me.

Any other fix I could try or something I could do?

Comment: Can you add to your `main` method, before the `launch ` call:  `System.setProperty(“prism.verbose”, “true”);`, run again and post the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it with setting the used JRE to the latest openjdk installed with brew.
Then I had to uncheck the `Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT` box in Run configurations in the VM tab, then it worked

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Java, having same issue. How did you fix it exactly? What command did you run to set the JRE to the openjdk? Thanks

Comment: @irina Hi! I went to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Clicked on the Java tab on the left side -> Installed JREs
Then I added a new one with this path `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`
I installed the JDK with 
`brew install openjdk`

Comment: This worked great, thanks a lot!!